# Wiring question for new ceiling lights

Tags: electrical

Let me start with the electrical schematics for my house (built-in 1985) are quite bizarre; the house was constructed very quickly so the contractor could pull money for a bigger project. We've discovered many shortcuts over the last 35+ years. What you would think would align in the breaker box,   doesn't. It's been fun figuring out the connections over the years.

Here are my concerns:

I just installed two matching ceiling fixtures in the kitchen. Both operate from one double switch on the entry side of the kitchen and the main one near the sink/prep area has a secondary switch base by the exterior door. I did not work on the switches and after making connecting the new fixtures, work fine.

- First. The red,  or "hot" wire, was connected with the lesser used light and switch. There was no red wire with the main one. **Should this concern me?** I have switched out this fixture several times and never noticed that.   I didn't think about it until I went to the other fixture and thought they may have switched the lines for some reason when the house was built.
- Second. I had closed off the lesser-used fixture for some time and wanted to make sure capping off the black bundle and connecting the red to black on the fixture is still the way to go.  There's no fan or other aspect (*should have been simple black/white and no red*).
- Third.  The new fixtures' wires connect to the main wiring with the cap nuts fine, but cannot feed up into the box. I haven't seen this before. (*the fixtures have two lights each, and the wires just meet to connect together and then just to the main wires*)  **How is this going to impact going forward; do I need to worry about a potential fire hazard or should I go through and see if I can connect better, or splice in additional wire?**

Comment: Can you post photos of the situation you're in?

Comment: I've connected everything and set the glass on the fixtures and would rather not have to take them apart. However, if you feel it would help  - will do so,  but in the morning.

Comment: Your situation is rather confusing, so a diagram of how the wiring is laid out, _plus_ pictures of the actual switches and wiring behind the lights would be _very_ helpful. It _sounds_ like there is a primary light controlled by a single switch and a secondary light controlled by a pair of 3-way switches, but it's unclear. Also, not sure what "closed off the lesser-used fixture" really means. These are reasons that pictures are so important.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Yes, I do believe what occurred when the house was originally wired, they set up the two lights with the 3-way; however, the main work area light was wired as the secondary one, which has created part of the concern. The second light, which was not used all that much had been taken down for many years and the wires capped (closed-off and covered on the ceiling) and switch not used. When I saw the red wire, I just wanted to check that connecting red to black is still the way to go. I am working on taking at least one fixture back down to take the pictures of my concern about short fixture wires

Comment: Thank you for weighing in, ThreePhase and FreeMan - After taking down both fixtures (to do the photos), I did some additional folding and was able to get the wires up into the boxes. Old, really small boxes, so it's a tight fit for both, but accomplished. (will still post pictures once they come over from my phone).